# Servlet sessions

Tags: java, jsp, session

I have two Java servlets namely,

```
A.java and B.java
```

and a JSP page,

```
my.jsp
```

my.jsp sends session,

```
session.setAttribute("path", loc);
```

Which is accessible in A.java

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
String fpath = session.getAttribute("path").toString();
```

Which uses this session and relods my.jsp

```
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("my.jsp");
rd.forward(request, response);
```

After which, when I try to access the same session from my.jsp in B.java using

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
String b = session.getAttribute("path").toString();
```

b returns null. Giving a NullPointerException.

What to do? Why isn't it working?

Further info,

my.jsp has multiple buttons, when button A is clicked a.java gets executed and returns some stuff to display in my.jsp due to which my.jsp refreshes and button A is removed from my.jsp and when button B is clicked then comes b.java into picture and it shows the below screen.

On line 36, I have

```
    String b = session.getAttribute("path").toString();
```

[image]

Comment: logically it should work...unless u invalidated the session

Comment: I Know :( but is returning a nullpointer exception on the line getattribute("path").toString()

Comment: try setting the session again in a.java and checking in b.java

Comment: I assume both servlets are deployed within the same webapp/WAR file?

Comment: Okay, will update on checking. Hold on.

Comment: Yes, they are on the same webapp :D

Comment: Make sure that you are not invalidating the session and also not removing the attribute from session by calling session.removeAttribute(

Comment: @Ankit Nah! I've done nothing like that.

Comment: what is `loc` check that would be null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've understood that my session is getting refreshed.

So,

in my.jsp I've included stuff to check the existence of the session as shown below,

```
<%    
  String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("dd:MM:yyyy_HH:mm:ss:SSS").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
  timeStamp = timeStamp + ":" + System.nanoTime();
  HttpSession ses = request.getSession();
  if(ses == null || ses.getAttribute("path") == null)
{
  session.setAttribute("path", timeStamp);
}
  else
{
  session.getAttribute("path");
}
 %>
```

in Upload.java, I've received this session and added the received value back to the session again like this,

```
String fpath = request.getSession().getAttribute("path").toString();
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setAttribute("path", fpath);

    //Did my file upload stuff using apache commons

    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("my.jsp");
rd.forward(request, response);
```

Finally, in mu exec.java after using the session I am invalidating it

```
HttpSession ses = request.getSession();
ses.invalidate();
```

Now, I am able to access the session even when the page is being refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to `a.java`

```
session.setAttribute("path1", fpath);
```

and access the same in `b.java` as,

```
String b = session.getAttribute("path1").toString();
```

In b.java when you have been redirected to my.jsp, your loc variable is set to null.

Comment: @Zedai probably this line has something to do with it RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("my.jsp"); rd.forward(request, response);could u tell me the process?i mean from my.jsp to a.java then how does b.java come into picture?

Comment: Okay. See, my.jsp has multiple buttons, when button A is clicked a.java gets executed and returns some stuff to display in my.jsp due to which my.jsp refreshes and button A is removed from my.jsp and when button B is clicked then comes b.java into picture.

Comment: @Zedai ok....the second time wen u go from my.jsp to b.java,ur `loc` variable is null hence the session in my.jsp is set to null...probably `loc` is  left blank the 2nd time(i.e from my.jsp to b.java)...